Machine Learning Prediction Project: Getting "ValueError" After Submitting the Prediction Form in the Flask App on Localhost
What I am working on?
I am working on a Machine Learning project that predicts the price of electric vehicles in the different states of the USA. My goal is to solidify my practical skills. I have done everything in the project, like performing one-hot encoding, training the model, and running the Flask app on localhost.
In localhost, I have filled out the form with the following values and then clicked on the submit button:
County: Jefferson
City: PORT TOWNSEND
ZIP Code: 98368
Model Year: 2012
Make: NISSAN
Model: LEAF
Electric Vehicle Type: Battery Electric Vehicle (BEV)
CAFV Eligibility: Clean Alternative Fuel Vehicle Eligible
Legislative District: 24

What issue am I facing?
After submitting the form, I get this error:
ValueError
ValueError: Found unknown categories \['98368'\] in column 2 during transform

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1498, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1476, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1473, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 882, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 880, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 865, in dispatch_request
return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions\[rule.endpoint\])(\*\*view_args)  # type: ignore\[no-any-return\]
File "G:\\Machine_Learning_Projects\\austin\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\app\\routes.py", line 38, in predict
price = predict_price(features)
File "G:\\Machine_Learning_Projects\\austin\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\app\\model.py", line 29, in predict_price
transformed_features = encoder.transform(features_df)
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\utils_set_output.py", line 157, in wrapped
data_to_wrap = f(self, X, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 1027, in transform
X_int, X_mask = self.\_transform(
File "C:\\Users\\austin.conda\\envs\\electric_vehicle_price_prediction_2\\lib\\site-packages\\sklearn\\preprocessing_encoders.py", line 200, in \_transform
raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Found unknown categories \['98368'\] in column 2 during transform\

What did I try?
I tried using the following code:
Code of the routes.py file inside the app folder:
from flask import render_template, request, jsonify
from app import app
from app.model import predict_price
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

@app.route('/')
def index():
env = Environment(
loader=PackageLoader("app"),
autoescape=select_autoescape()
)
template = env.get_template("index.html")
return render_template(template)

@app.route('/predict', methods=\['POST'\])
def predict():
data = request.form.to_dict()

    # Convert the form data into the correct format for prediction
    features = [
        data['county'],
        data['city'],
        data['zip_code'],
        data['model_year'],
        data['make'],
        data['model'],
        data['ev_type'],
        data['cafv_eligibility'],
        data['legislative_district']
    ]
    
    # Get the prediction result
    price = predict_price(features)
    
    return jsonify({'predicted_price': price})

Code of the model.py file inside the app folder:
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
import joblib
from flask import Flask, render_template
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader, PackageLoader, select_autoescape

env = Environment(
loader=PackageLoader("app"),
autoescape=select_autoescape()
)

model = joblib.load('model/ev_price_model.pkl')

def predict_price(features):
    encoder = joblib.load('model/encoder.pkl')  # Load encoder if needed
    
    features_df = pd.DataFrame([features], columns=['County', 'City', 'ZIP Code', 'Model Year', 'Make', 'Model', 'Electric Vehicle Type', 'Clean Alternative Fuel Vehicle (CAFV) Eligibility', 'Legislative District'])
    
    # Apply encoding, scaling, etc., if necessary
    transformed_features = encoder.transform(features_df)
    
    # Make the prediction
    price = model.predict(transformed_features)
    
    return price[0]  # Assuming it returns a single value


What is the link to my GitHub repository?
Here is the link to my repo:
https://github.com/SteveAustin583/electric-vehicle-price-prediction
What I was expecting?
I was expecting to get the prediction result without any issue. Because I have already performed one-hot encoding.
Can you help me fixing this issue?

How did you encode the zip codes? do you have 98368 as a zip code in your training dataset?

@rehaqds I have 98368 as a zip code in n=my training dataset.

But it seems that you didn't use all your training set to train the encoder and 98368 is not in zips_e. Also strange to see the zip code as a float (".0"), when you fill your form do you also write 98368.0 ?

@rehaqds No, I didn't fill my form by writing 98368.0. I wrote 98368.

Looks like the problem is that 98368(.0) zip code is not in zips_e so the encoder which was trained on zips_e data doesn't know what to do with this new category.

@rehaqds I am actually confused with your explanation. Are you referring to encoder.pkl file? And I did use zip code as a feature while encoding. You can see it here: https://github.com/SteveAustin583/electric-vehicle-price-prediction/blob/main/app/model.py

Please look at your jupyter notebook. The encoder for zipcodes is trained on zips_e data. But 98368(.0) that you entered in your form is not in the training data so what should the encoder do? If you look at the doc for OneHotEncoder (https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) you will see that by default handle_unknown='error'. That's why an error was raised.

@rehaqds I see. So, what would you recommend me to do? Should I start everything from scratch, separate numerical columns and categorical columns, apply transform, and then perform prediction in Jupyter notebook? And once I am done with the notebook, I will work on creating Flask app accordingly?

The encoder is being applied to the entire dataset, which is probably giving the incorrect results
I think it's better to define separate transforms
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder, StandardScaler

num_transformer = StandardScaler()
cat_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')

# create a preprocessor using columntransformer from sklearn
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', num_transformer, numerical_cols),
        ('cat', cat_transformer, categorical_cols),
    ]
)

# combine into single pipeline
model = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('regressor', RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42))
])

Then apply
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

Modify the inference similarly.
Let me know if this helps with your problem.
Edit:
Another way to separate and convert x data to ohencoded values in a simpler way is:
x_categorical = df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).apply(ohe.fit_transform)
x_numerical = df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']).values

Then combine
x = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(x_numerical), x_categorical], axis=1).values


Ok. I will take a look at it and come back to you. I tried to upvote your answer. But as I am a new member, I am not being allowed to do it sadly.

In my code, I didn't use any code that defines categorical columns and numerical columns. Do you want me to do that?
My code is quite different from the typical Machine Learning project codes. which do define categorical columns and numerical columns like the way you are trying to do.

My code is different because of three reasons:

I found a dataset about electric vehicle price prediction at kaggle and really liked it
I found a jupyter notebook on kaggle. Here is the link: https://www.kaggle.com/code/vitb19mim10050/ev-price-prediction-2
I tell ChatGPT to use that notebook to generate code for a Machine Learning Prediction Flask app.

Initially there were some issues. But I overcome those challenges to run the app on localhost.
Now, if I follow your procedure, I think I will have to make adjustment to my code on Jupyter Notebook as well. Am I right?

Yes, you’ll have to use different transforms, since strings get categorised, but numbers don’t. Alternatively, you can look into ‘pd.get_dummies()’ function here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html Additionally, do check the datatype of the columns, make sure the numerical data is not of Object type since I did not get to run your code and check myself.

Alright. I think I have to start working on this project from scratch, like first creating a Jupyter Notebook with code that defines categorical columns and numerical columns. And once I am done with that, I will work on creating the Flask app. I am going to choose your answer as the right one.
